# Disable Trigger On A Single Insert Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an AFTER INSERT trigger that works fine for single row inserts but performs poorly with  an INSERT SELECT statement that inserts > 10,000 rows/

Is it possible to disable a trigger at a statement level e.g. for a single INSERT SELECT statement?

Comment: 10,000 rows isn't a lot. I suspect a trigger. It would be better to re-write the trigger to not perform badly here.

Comment: All the trigger is doing is calling a SQL Server geography function whose performance is outwith# our control

Comment: Can you drop the trigger, run the statement, then recreate the trigger; all in the same transaction?

Comment: I was wondering about that. I guess I was worried about side effects for other users of the system / other processes that insert into this table at this point. But may be an option.

Comment: You might change the trigger to perform the job only if there is just one row - `if (select count(*) from inserted) = 1 begin ... end`.

Answer (score 2):

```
DISABLE TRIGGER dbo.MyTrigger ON dbo.MyTable

EXEC MyGeographyStoredProcedure

ENABLE TRIGGER dbo.MyTrigger ON dbo.MyTable
```

or

```
DISABLE TRIGGER dbo.MyTrigger ON dbo.MyTable

INSERT LudicrousNumberofRows FROM BigDataset

ENABLE TRIGGER dbo.MyTrigger ON dbo.MyTable
```

Comment: just cross your fingers that no other inserts occur while your procedure runs or you insert your row.  in my experience, over the long term, this will result in "phantom" problems because the trigger will be disabled when it needs to run. see my answer for a more reliable solution.

Answer (score 1):

when you disable the trigger it is for everyone, not just your connection.  So why try to disable it and cause potential problems with other inserts?

in beginning of the the trigger do:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT top 2 COUNT(1) FROM INSERTED HAVING COUNT(1)>1)
BEGIN
    --possibly insert into some other "work needs to be done table"
    --where you have a running job pull this info and work on it
    --so this trigger doesn't need to do it, you just delay the work
    --and let the job do it.
    RETURN --exit the trigger without doing any of the "slow processing"
END
```

Answer (score 0):

another option:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename DISABLE TRIGGER ALL 
-- do work here 
ALTER TABLE tablename ENABLE TRIGGER ALL
```

use it if you have only one trigger or what to disable all triggers on a table :)